# Show the database last data, first in the listView

Tags: android, database, listview

when we select data from mysql database and show it in list view, then the 1st data of the database showed in the first of the list.

I want to show the first data in the last of the listView and last data in the first of the list.

Is there any method to do it?

Comment: what database? you mean local sqlite database?

Comment: No. Mysql database.

Answer (score 1):

Use this..

```
  SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase=dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "select * from " + TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);

cursor.moveToLast();
 while (cursor.moveToPrevious())
        {
//Your code here
.
.
.
}
```